# Add Multiple Elements to PDF via jsPDF's addHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pdf, jspdf

I am using an [angular-ui tabset](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to display several separate bits of information. Because the actual content of the tabs that aren't active is hidden, it does not print if I just add the entire body of the page. The only tab content that you see after printing is the currently active tab. I'm attempting to print everything inside of these tabs along with another single element from the page using the `addHTML` method to preserve the way that it looks.

Printing any of these individually works well, but I can't seem to find a way to print all of the items at once.

For example, this is the code used to print a single element.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML($('#foo').first(), function() {
    pdf.save();
});
```

That works (although the output *is* all black, but I suppose that's a separate issue). Now, I would like to have several `addHTML` statements to finish adding the content I need and then save. Something like

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
pdf.addHTML($('#foo').first());
_.each( $('.bar').first().children(), function(e) {
    pdf.addHTML(e);
});
pdf.save();
```

However, taking the second approach when the pdf is saved, it is just completely blank.

It's worth noting that this works, but it doesn't have the formatting that I would like to keep *and* has more content than I'd like:

```
  var doc = new jsPDF();

  doc.fromHTML($('body').get(0), 15, 15, {
    'width': 170,
  }, function() {
    doc.save();
  });
```

Attempting to force it to select just `#foo` and `.bar` ends up coming out to the same problem that I have above.

Any suggestoins on the correct way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam's answer never quite worked for me, for one reason or another. Instead, I went with the approach of creating a new div, appending all of my stuff to it, printing it, and then destroying it. That can be accomplished via something along these lines:

```
      var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','letter');

      $("#printing-holder").append("<div id='printingDiv' style='background-color: white;'></div>");
      ($('#foo')).clone().appendTo("#printingDiv");
      _.each( $('.bar').children(), function(e) {
        $("#printingDiv").append('<br/>');
        $(e).clone().appendTo("#printingDiv");
        $("#printingDiv").append('<br/>');
      });
      pdf.addHTML(($("#printingDiv")[0]), {pagesplit: true}, function() {
        console.log("THING");
        pdf.save();
        $("#printingDiv").remove();
      });
```

Note that the `pagesplit` option splits the image up if it is larger than one page, but (as of the date of this answer) seems to vastly lower the quality of the PDF generated.

Comment: Hi @Linell, I tried your approach but i am getting `ReferenceError: CanvasRenderer is not defined at renderWindow`. I am guessing this is due to some missing dependency js. Can you please point me to the right js file(s) that I need to include to get this to work? PS: My page has a lot of canvas elements that I want to publish to the PDF that I create.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `pdf.save()` outside of the addHTML callback will most likely create the pdf before the addHTML method had a chance to add the html. Try something like this:

**Not tested**

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
var elements = $(".bar");
var i = 0;
var recursiveAddHtml = function () {
    if (i < elements.length) {
        var x = 0, y = i * 20; 
        pdf.addHTML(elements.get(i), x, y, function () {
            i++;
            recursiveAddHtml();
        });
    } else {
        pdf.save();
    }
}

recursiveAddHtml();
```

This should call `recursiveAddHtml` for each element, one at a time, then call `save` when it reaches the end.

**Update**

I just tried this out and it seems to work, except that it positions all elements on top of each other. I'm not sure how to detect the height of the content currently in the pdf yet, so I added x and y coordinates to the example so you can at least see the different elements in the PDF.

Also, make sure you set the background-color to something otherwise it defaults to black.

Comment: Hmm... I think that you're on to the right idea there, but my `pdf.save()` is never actually being called. My `elements.length` is 5, *but* a console.log inside of the recursiveAddHtml function only outputting three times. Check out this image of it http://imgur.com/DntH44M (and this gist of the code https://gist.github.com/Linell/c0521f5dde8a59239e99)

Comment: Is that when the error about picture001.jpg is being thrown? If that image is hosted on a different server, you may be getting a security error that is preventing the rest of the elements from being added.

Comment: I thought about that, *but* that's being thrown in the first couple too and it isn't stopping it there.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the content of the element that's having trouble. Could there be some element within the element you are adding that canvas doesn't understand? Or I've noticed it also will fail if there is no content.