# js code to get the dynamic generated div IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jspdf

I am working on java and angularjs application.
I have a html page which iterates the object and display the values on page.

html code:

```
<div id="{{value.pageIndex}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in employees" class="myDivClass">
    <div>
         <h1><font color="red"> {{value.pageHeader}}</font></h1>
    </div>
    <div>
         <h1> {{value.pageIndex}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div>text from html page</div>
</div>
```

I should not enclose the above html code inside another div as it will fail my other scenario's in my application.

I want to export the above html content to the PDF when user click on a button, issue is when i'm trying to get the value from html page as shown in below js code, only first iterated data is exported where as i want the entire data to be exported to the PDF.

js code:

```
$scope.export = function() {
   var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape');
    source = $('.one1');
    pdf.addHTML(source, 0, 0, {
        pagesplit: true
    },function(dispose){
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
    });
}
```

Please find the demo of the above scenario: https://plnkr.co/edit/6jNIu5c26ACeTPsfACX2?p=preview

Any suggestions on how to pass the dynamic generated ID's to the js code and export the entire html data to PDF? Is there any way to pass dynamic generated ID's to the js code and export the entire data to the PDF.

PS: I should not enclose the above html code inside another div as it will fail my other scenario's in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the class `myDivClass` to fetch your data instead of using `id` attribute.

You can use jQuery `.each()` to fetch all the data.

Add append-source div to html

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="listController">
        <button ng-click="export()">export</button>

   <div id="{{value.pageIndex}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in employees" class="myDivClass">
    <div>  <h1><font color="red"> {{value.pageHeader}}</font></h1> </div>
    <div><h1> {{value.pageIndex}}</h1></div>
    <div>text from html page</div>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div id="append-source"></div>
</body>
```

Use this div to create pdf in JavaScript

```
$scope.export = function() {
   var pdf = new jsPDF('landscape');
   var source = $('#append-source');
    $('.myDivClass').each(function(){
      var html = $(this);
      source.append(html);
    });
    console.log(source);
    pdf.addHTML(
          source, 0, 0, {
              pagesplit: true
          },
          function(dispose){
              pdf.save('test.pdf');
          }
      );
     }
```

Comment: Can you please modify https://plnkr.co/edit/6jNIu5c26ACeTPsfACX2?p=preview. I just updated the link in my post above,thanks.

Comment: @user8838953 Sorry... I've never used plunker but I think you're nearly there. I think you just need to change source = $('.myDivClass') to source = $('.myDivClass').each();

Comment: I used that but turned up with error, it says 'Cannot read property call of undefined'

Comment: @user8838953 Plunker is cool. I think I got it working. You need to add another div to html that you can append data to and then use that div to create your pdf. I'll add the code to the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the inputs..I have some other issue with the above code, i will post the question now..

Comment: I'm facing one issue with the above code, i have to hide few div elements exporting to PDF. When i used   $(".dontExport1").attr("hidden", true) it is hiding the div content and not displaying in PDF. But the html page displayed after user clicked on export button is changing accordingly and not displaying the hidden content and i know this is because of <div id="append-source"></div> . Is there any work around to come out of this issue, else i cannot use this code. Any inputs would be very helpful. This is the updated plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/haEWQTXd2L3RBMdykNrn?p=preview @Derek Nolan

Comment: @user8838953 Can you use $(".dontExport1").remove(); within the .each() function.

Comment: I want to copy the div content which has data to the empty div (id="append-source") as you suggested in the accepted answer above, and then export the content to the PDF. How can I achieve the same for my code here https://plnkr.co/edit/o7we6Q00NixwvVkms5EF?p=preview . Any inputs would be helpful as I'm stuck at this scenario. In my application if I am trying to export the div with content directly it is exporting some additional information too.@Derek Nolan

Comment: I think it might be best to try something like in this answer. The same method of appending to a div before saving is used. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240788/add-multiple-elements-to-pdf-via-jspdfs-addhtml